# Xamarin Service Alarmmanager Weekly Notification

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, service, alarmmanager

I am having issues with my service and alarmmanager. During debug I notice the code being hit, but I am not getting a notification at the specified day and time. With the code below could someone give me some information as to why it isn't going off.

```
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        Intent managerIntent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        managerIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmNotificationReceiver));
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, managerIntent, 0);

        //setting Calendar
        Java.Util.Calendar calendar = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
        calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfWeek, 2);
        calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, 14);



        //manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 3000, 60 + 1000, pendingIntent);
        // manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, pendingIntent);
       // manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, pendingIntent);
        manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + calendar.TimeInMillis, AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, pendingIntent);
```

So the below commented code actually does work as intended. I tested with it kicking off for the first time in 30 minutes and 30 minutes repeating.  But the above uncommented line does not work for kicking off in a half hour and at the specificied day and time every week.

// manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, pendingIntent);

Comment: Did the alarm triggered later? Because as of API 19 all the repeating alarm are inexact. Please refer to [AlarmManager.SetRepeating](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: No I still haven't received the alarm. Are you saying I should try and test with setinexact?

Comment: Mean to say *Setexact?

Comment: So i tried the below code and still no luck
manager.SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, pendingIntent);

Comment: This has been answer under this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656498/alarm-goes-off-everytime-i-open-the-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656498/alarm-goes-off-everytime-i-open-the-app
This was answered in the above link.