# Alarm Goes off everytime I open the App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, service, alarmmanager

I can't figure out why whenever I open my app my notification set to go off by an alarm is set off.  I have it set on a calendar for only a specific day and time.  Not only that my alarm isn't even going off at the specified time and day of the week from the calendar.  Do i even need a service with my alarm? I am trying to make sure this goes off even when the application is closed.

The code below (MyService) is called in MainActivity onCreate().

```
[Service]
public class MyService : Service
{

    //const int NOTIFICATION_ID = 9000;

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        SetAlarm();

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    private void SetAlarm()
    {

        //setting Calendar
        Java.Util.Calendar calendar = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
        calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfWeek, 1);
        calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, 02);
        calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, 15);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        Intent managerIntent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        managerIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmNotificationReceiver));
        // pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, managerIntent, 0);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, managerIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);


        //manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 3000, 60 + 1000, pendingIntent);
        // manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, pendingIntent);
        // manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, pendingIntent);
        manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, 604800, pendingIntent);

    }

[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        builder.SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
            .SetContentTitle("Comic Pull List")
            .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText("New Comics have came out this week! Check your list and pull comics if needed."))
            .SetContentText("New Comics have came out this week! Check your list and pull comics if needed.");

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        manager.Notify(1, builder.Build());


    }
}
```

}

My new code i added is below:

```
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

        //setting Calendar
        Java.Util.Calendar calendar = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
        if (calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfWeek) == Java.Util.Calendar.Wednesday)
        {
            calendar.Add(Java.Util.CalendarField.Date, 4);
        }
        while (calendar.Get(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfWeek) != Java.Util.Calendar.Wednesday)
        {
            calendar.Add(Java.Util.CalendarField.Date, 4);
        }
        //calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfWeek, 1);
        calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, 15);
        calendar.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, 30);


        Intent managerIntent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        managerIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmNotificationReceiver));
        // pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, managerIntent, 0);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, managerIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);


        //manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 3000, 60 + 1000, pendingIntent);
        // manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, pendingIntent);
        // manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, AlarmManager.IntervalHalfHour, pendingIntent);
        manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the first alarm in the past.

> If the trigger time you specify is in the past, the alarm triggers immediately.

You need to set the date to the *next* Sunday.

#### Example:

```
using (AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService))
using (var calendar = Calendar.Instance)
{
    if (calendar.Get(CalendarField.DayOfWeek) == Calendar.Sunday)
        calendar.Add(CalendarField.Date, 1);
    while (calendar.Get(CalendarField.DayOfWeek) != Calendar.Sunday)
        calendar.Add(CalendarField.Date, 1);
    calendar.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, 02);
    calendar.Set(CalendarField.Minute, 15);
    Log.Debug("SO", $"Current date is   : {Calendar.Instance.Time.ToString()}");
    Log.Debug("SO", $"Alarm will fire at {calendar.Time.ToString()}");
    var managerIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, managerIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
    manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, pendingIntent);
}
```

#### Output:

```
[SO] Current date is   : Sat Aug 12 23:01:11 PDT 2017
[SO] Alarm will fire at: Sun Aug 13 02:15:11 PDT 2017
```

Comment: So it will start next Sunday then continue to go off only on Sundays?

Comment: @Freiza1991 `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7` = 7 days in milliseconds, try it by running your app once and then changing the time of your device to the next Sunday.

Comment: Okay so i set the time to go off on Wednesday ran it once and then set my date/change on my phone to match it and I am getting no notification this time. I added my new code to the bottom of my post for reference.

Comment: @Freiza1991 You change both `calendar.Add` calls from 1 day to 4 days??? You might want to read up on how `Calender` works: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: I did do that and it didn't work.  I have my code posted for reference

Comment: @Freiza1991 Set a breakpoint after setting the calendar or add  `Log` statements and check the date that the calendar is set to...

Comment: Okay so i added the log statement and i got the below:
(21013): Current date is   : Sun Aug 13 10:39:05 CDT 2017
(21013): Alarm will fire at Wed Sep 06 15:30:56 CDT 2017

It is going ahead by 4 weds. Is this because the while loop is reiterating four times adding to the calendar four times?

Comment: @Freiza1991 Like I said, you changed the calendar.Add calls from 1 day to 4 days.... change it back to one day.

Comment: Ah okay i changed both of them back to 1 and that did the trick. Thank you so much! Very helpful.