# Background Service in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a background service in android is implemented as :

```
 [Service]
public class PeriodicService : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        // From shared code or in your PCL]
        Task.Run(() => {
            MessagingCenter.Send<string>(this.Class.Name, "SendNoti");
        });

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

}
```

In MainActivity Class :

```
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        UserDialogs.Init(() => (Activity)Forms.Context);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(PeriodicService)));
    }
}
```

In Xamarin Forms in My login page :

```
 public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int i = 0;
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "SendNoti", (e) =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                i++;

                CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Some Text", "This is notification!");                        

                }
            });
        });

    }
```

The main problem here is my Periodic service is not sending any message except for the first time. The notification is shown only once! Please help.

Comment: You are only calling `MessagingCenter.Send` **once** in your service...

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you for your answer. So how can I send that notification every n hours?

Comment: Using a repeating alarm via AlarmManager/SetRepeating is a much better way to schedule re-occuring events, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45657600/4984832

Comment: Actually, this is not a alarm, its a notification so I cannot send alarms as you have done in the answer.

Comment: You should read up on pending intents and intent services, the Alarm manager is prefect for your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an **`IntentService`** to send your notifications:

```
[Service(Label = "NotificationIntentService")]
public class NotificationIntentService : IntentService
{
    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        var notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                           .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo)
                           .SetContentTitle("StackOverflow")
                           .SetContentText("Some text.......")
                           .Build();
        ((NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService)).Notify((new Random()).Next(), notification);
    }
}
```

Then use the **`AlarmManager`** to setup a repeating alarm using a pending intent that "calls" your `IntentService`:

```
using (var manager = (Android.App.AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService))
{
    // Send a Notification in ~60 seconds and then every ~90 seconds after that....
    var alarmIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationIntentService));
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
    manager.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, 1000 * 60, 1000 * 90, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: I am sure this works but, a little more help please, how do I set notification every day at 10 am, 2pm and 5pm? also if device was switched off at that time i need to send a notification later.

Comment: Thanks , I marked this as the answer and I found the solution to my question as well :)