# AlarmManager fires off for past time in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

This is my code for alarm manager class

```
   public void Remind(int hour ,int minute, string title, string message,int day)
        {
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(MainActivity.AlarmReceiver));
             alarmIntent.PutExtra("message", message);
            alarmIntent.PutExtra("title", title);
            int x = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Forms.Context, DateTime.Now.Millisecond, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
            Java.Util.Date date = new Java.Util.Date();
            Java.Util.Calendar cal = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;

            cal.TimeInMillis = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();

            cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, hour);
            cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, minute);
            cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Second, 0);
            cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfMonth, day);


            AlarmManager alarmManager = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
            alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, cal.TimeInMillis, pendingIntent);


        }
```

And BroadcastReceiver in MainActivity ;

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
    public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            var message = intent.GetStringExtra("message");
            var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");

            var notIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));

            var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, DateTime.Now.Millisecond, notIntent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
            var manager = Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationManagerCompat.From(context);

            var style = new Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            style.BigText(message);

            int resourceId;

            resourceId = Resource.Drawable.icon;

            var wearableExtender = new Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
    .SetBackground(Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, resourceId))
                ;

            //Generate a notification with just short text and small icon



            var builder = new Android.Support.V7.App.NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .SetContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                     .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                            .SetContentTitle(title)
                            .SetContentText(message)
                            .SetStyle(style)
                            .SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
                            .SetAutoCancel(true)
                            .Extend(wearableExtender);

            var notification = builder.Build();
            manager.Notify(DateTime.Now.Millisecond, notification);
        }
    }

}
```

The code works great if i select the alarm to fire off at a future hour/minute.

**The application contains five alarmsChange daily**

If i open the application ..  before these times everything is very good and alarms fire in real time .. but if i open it After any time of the five ...All past Alarms fire off

**Example:**

now it is 15:00 , i set the alarm for 15:45, alarm goes off at 15:45, everything ok

now it is 15:00 , i set the alarm for 14:30, the alarm goes off when open the application

Comment: `now it is 15:00 , i set the alarm for 14:30` : For the 14:30, you need to set it to the **next day**. Related example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45657600/4984832

Comment: This trick is good and work with me but I don't want to repeat  the notifications that were in the past because in the next week I will send it in  new times not the same old times so if I used this trick notification will send for two times

Comment: When you add your 5 RtcWakeup alarms, **if** the "time of day" for one if less than the "current time of day", you need to add a day to the calendar for it, otherwise you are setting it in the past. Otherwise do not set an alarm if it in the past and only set one of your 5 alarms that are in the future.